# Most active hours per day in Firebase Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

How can one find in which hours user are most active? There are charts that show daily users, but I need a chart to show for example "active hours" or "traffic per hour in 24 hour" per last week or last month.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632952/can-google-analytics-show-me-visits-by-hour

Comment: @user0 As I mentioned, I am looking for Firebase Hourly Report, not Google Analytics.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly that is impossible with Google Firebase Analytics. And yes, Google is [deprecating and shutting down](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en) their superb Google Analytics SDK in 4 months and forces App developers to use their "new" highly praised Firebase Analytics, which is even NOT able to show us numbers per hour, or the number of new/returning users for today.